# how to get stack trace c++ functions names in android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, stack-trace

I am looking for a native crash in my application but i cant find a tool that help me to translate the address to the function names in my library i saw this post : [how to use addr2line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android) but it seems that only works when you have a trace like this :

```
I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic:2.3/GRH55/79397:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 378, tid: 386  >>> com.example.gltest <<<
I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 001dbdc0  r1 00000001  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000000  r5 40a40000  r6 4051a480  r7 42ddbee8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 43661b24  r9 42ddbed0  10 42ddbebc  fp 41e462d8
I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 00000001  sp 436619d0  lr 83a12f5d  pc 8383deb4  cpsr 20000010
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0003deb4  /data/data/com.example.gltest/lib/libnativemaprender.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 00039b76  /data/data/com.example.gltest/lib/libnativemaprender.so
I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 00017d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

as you can see in the last 3 lines the library of your application is there : **ibnativemaprender.so**

and only if your library appear there the addr2line app will work

but in my trace i have this :

```
I/DEBUG   (16251):          #00  pc 000161c0  /system/lib/libc.so 
I/DEBUG   (16251):          #01  lr afd196f1  /system/lib/libc.so
```

and my library is not show there until later :

```
/DEBUG   (16251): stack: 
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c818  afd426a4     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c81c  000b7290     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c820  00000afa    
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c824  afd187b9  /system/lib/libc.so    
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c828  afd42644     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c82c  afd467c4     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c830  00000000     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c834  afd196f1  /system/lib/libc.so   
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c838  00000001     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c83c  46f0c86c     
I/DEBUG   (16251):     46f0c840  81b6a4a0  /data/data/com.android.ANMP/lib/mylib.so
```

so is there a tool that can help me? or a different way to use addr2line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. To do that you need to perform the search manually.

Manually, there are a three options:

- Add debug prints to find out where and when it happens
- Use IDA pro, (which is very expensive tool), load your library into it and look for the address `81b6a4a0`, try to figure out which function it is. If you compile  with debug symbols it should be easy enough.
- Find the base address of your library, use objdump (from the NDK toolchain) to find what's in the address `81b6a4a0` (after removing base address from it).

In both last ways, if you don't find anything helpful, pull **libc.so** and **libdvm.so** from the device using **adb** and try to find what are the functions that appears in the stack trace, then check where do you call those functions in your code.

Comment: and what do you mean by manually search?, you mean like printing information every time i enter and exit on every method?

Comment: how useful is the ndk-stack tool?

Comment: @MobileCushion - I have never used it

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083154/how-can-i-catch-sigsegv-segmentation-fault-and-get-a-stack-trace-under-jni-on/1789879#1789879). I have not yet found the time to try, so tell if if worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB to get stack traces.  If you have a rooted phone or use the emulator you can enable core dumps. Then you can use GDB to examine the core dumps.

See this question for setting up GDB in Eclipse:

[android how to use ndk gdb with a pure native executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627949/android-how-to-use-ndk-gdb-with-a-pure-native-executable/8629652#8629652)